# Jessie plugin integration with Frama-c Aluminium

Tags: static-analysis, frama-c, why3

How to integrate 
Jessie an external plugin(why 2.36) with 
Frama-c Aluminium?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Why 2.36 is only compatible with Frama-C Magnesium. However, the master branch of Why's git repository seems to be compatible with Frama-C Aluminium (disclaimer: I've only checked that the plugin compiles fine, but didn't attempt to do any proof with it).

The git repository is located at https://scm.gforge.inria.fr/anonscm/git/why/why.git/ It can be installed through the following steps:

`git clone https://scm.gforge.inria.fr/anonscm/git/why/why.git/
cd why
autoconf
./configure [--prefix=MY_LOCAL_INSTALL]
make
[sudo] make install`

Optionnally, if you're using opam, it can also be installed as a pinned version of why:

`opam pin add why --kind git --edit https://scm.gforge.inria.fr/anonscm/git/why/why.git/
[ you will be able to edit the opam instruction file: change the version
  number to something like 9999 and add ["autoconf"] at the top of the list
  of build steps ]`